# Umbraco - different behaviour for usual and ajax requests

Tags: umbraco

I'm developing an Umbraco site that is a "single page" - no reload, only ajax calls.

The site will have nice urls and use html5 push state history.

The problem here is that every time a request is made to the server I need to handle it differently depending on the type of the request: normal or ajax.

For usual requests I need to display the content along with it's master page.

For ajax requests I need to display only the content.

I don't know how to accomplish this - routing and master page magic.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use alternate templates. For more information [see here](http://www.nibble.be/?p=42). Basically, have the alternate template just render out the content in whatever format you want, without the full html template, and then make sure that all your AJAX requests call the pages using the alternate template.

One word of warning though, if you're doing all the site navigation with AJAX and no page reloads, then Google (or most other search engine spiders for that matter) won't be able to index your site properly (as they don't process javascript) and your site won't rank very well.

Comment: That is precisely why I want to handle ajax requests in different manner. I need to provide snapshots for google.